# Stacking a ribbon graph - ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to stack  ribbon graph, but am unable to do so.  Here is the data:

Here is a link to the data: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4961355/Port_of_Santos.csv

Here is the code I am running:

```
qplot(data = data, x = Date, y = Market.Share, geom = "ribbon", 
    fill = Company, group = Company, ymin = Market.Share - Market.Share/4, 
    ymax = Market.Share + Market.Share/4, alpha = .3)
```

The resulting graph is rather pretty, but I would really like the resulting graph would stack the ribbons in the end.  Also I would like the lines to be a little smoother...

I am tying to get to a graph like this one:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "stack the ribbons in the end"?

Comment: Sure, if you see the graph, the ribbons are stacked in the beginning and the end - they only overlap in the middle.  
I was hopping to achieve the same thing.